# Show Other page on a single page for web in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to create a single page Application by using Ionic 4 platform. I have already Ionic 4 App but I want to develop a SPA by using this Ionic App code. When I use one page to another page it's through an error. by using is code

```
    <app-horse-drifter></app-horse-drifter>
```

and include component in home page compnent.

Error: Type HorseDrifterPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: HomePageModule and HorseDrifterPageModule! Please consider moving HorseDrifterPage to a higher module that imports HomePageModule and HorseDrifterPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HorseDrifterPage then import that NgModule in HomePageModule and HorseDrifterPageModule.

Answer (score 0):

comment out `HorseDrifterPage` from the declarations' array of `horse-drift.module.ts`.

You are having the issue because it is declared in two places.

Comment: Yeah ! i know. but how to fix

Comment: that is why I said you should comment out HorseDrifterPage from the declarations' array of horse-drift.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Some people using Lazy loading are going to stumble across this page.

Here is what I did to fix sharing a directive.

1. create a new HorseDrifter Page

   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HorseDrifterPage } from './horse-drifter.page';

   const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HorseDrifterPage
      }
    ];

   @NgModule({
    imports: [
     RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    declarations: [HorseDrifterPage],
    exports: [HorseDrifterPage]
    })
   export class HorseDrifterPageModule {}

Then in home.module and your other module(s)

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
 RouterModule.forChild(routes),
 HorseDrifterPageModule
 ],
 declarations: [HomePage],
})
```